# CS0019 C# Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Tags: asp.net, linq

Can anyone help me how to do this query:

```
var x = db.Home.Where(b => b.HomeID == id).Select(b => b.Longitude && b.Latitude).ToList();
```

I want to select Latitude and Longitude values.

Comment: Why the <sql> tag? I see no SQL there.

Comment: So what are you wanting? Do you want Lat and Long available as two separate values or are you trying to *combine* them into a single value?

Comment: I want Lat and Long values as separate

Comment: Do you have a model where you store Longitude and Latitude?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will select the columns and will return anonymous type.

```
.Select(b => new { Longitude = b.Longitude, Latitude = b.Latitude })
```

Comment: thaaaanks a looot